# tuple access: Can't find a fixed record type

Tags: tuples, sml, records

I wrote a function that is supposed to receive a list of tuples. I access the components of the tuples with `#` and the code compiles:

```
fun recheck ([], n) = []
  | recheck (h::t, n) = 
    if ((#1 h) *  (#1 h)) +  ((#2 h) * (#2 h)) = n then
    h::recheck(t, n)
    else
    recheck(t, n)
```

But another function that basically does the same thing, namely receiving a list of tuples and accessing those, causes an error.

```
fun validate ([]) = true
  | validate (h::t)  = 
    if 1 = (#1 h) then
    true
    else
    false

Can't find a fixed record type.   Found near #1
```

What is the difference here and why does the latter cause an error?

## Edit

The first function actually does not compile on its own.

But this entire snippet does:

```
fun drop ([], n) = []
  | drop (h::t, 0) = h::t
  | drop (h::t, n) =
    drop(t, n-1) 

fun sts_linear (y, n) =
  if y < (Math.sqrt(n)+1.0) then
      let
      (* x^2 + y^2 = n => x = sqrt(n-y^2) *)
      val x = Math.sqrt(n - (y * y));
      val xr  = Real.realRound(x);
      in
  if (abs(x - xr) < 0.000000001)  then
          [(Real.trunc xr, Real.trunc y)]@sts_linear (y+1.0, n)
      else
          (
        []@sts_linear (y+1.0, n)
          )
      end
  else []

fun recheck ([], n) = []
  | recheck (h::t, n) =
    if ((#1 h) *  (#1 h)) +  ((#2 h) * (#2 h)) = n then
    h::recheck(t, n)
    else
    recheck(t, n)

fun sts (n) =
  (
    let
        val pairs = sts_linear(0.0, Real.fromInt n);
    in
        recheck(drop(pairs, Real.ceil( Real.fromInt (length(pairs))/2.0 ) ), n)
    end
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code *doesn't* compile, at least with SML/NJ:

[image]

If you got it to compile then it must have been in a nonstandard extension of SML.

The problem with both of your definitions is that there is no polymorphic idea of a `tuple` of arbitrary arity in SML. You can write functions to work on lists of pairs. You can write functions to work on lists of triples. But -- you can't write functions to work simultaneously on lists of pairs and lists of triples (at least if your function tries to do things with these pairs/triples as tuples).

One solution is to get rid of `#` and use pattern-matching to extract the components:

```
fun validate [] = true
|   validate ((x,y)::t)  = 
        if x = 1 then
            true
        else
            false
```

But, if you really want to write a function which can polymorphically apply to either lists of pairs or list of triples (or quadruples,...), the easiest thing to do is to represent the pairs, triples, etc. as lists rather than tuples. Lists which contains lists of nonspecified size are not a problem in SML.

Comment: You are right, it does not compile on its own. But when called from another function it does... weird. I have edited my startpost with the additional code that makes it compile.

Comment: I can't get the edited version to compile either. What is `drop`? It might be the case that if you have a whole-file compilation and there is enough type information in some function definitions to remove the ambiguity from other function definitions, then some compilers at least allow for it. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the `drop` method, I compiled the file and it worked, but only because I had loaded `drop` from a previous compilation... I did not know yet that function will be remembered once they were compiled once during a session. I am using PolyML.

Comment: Must be a PolyML extension. SML/NJ still doesn't like it (although I loaded it via `use` rather than via the not-very-easy to use compiler manager).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to minimize this down, as I have seen the following work in SML/NJ
and i'm not aware of it actually being a compiler extension

```
val p1 = {x=0, y=0};
val p2 = {x=1, y=1};
val p3 = {x=1, y=1, z=1};
```

There is an awkward construct from a compiler error perspective
not many languages have errors that work in this fashion,
because the function is valid, but produces a type error
unless an invocation of the function exists to resolve the
type of 'record', thus to resolve the error more code must be added.

```
fun getFoo(field) = fn record => field record;
```

Without the following actual calling of the getX
the compiler cannot determine the type of *record*
of which the complete type information of ALL fields
of the record must be known to the compiler, not just the #x field.

```
let val getX = getFoo(#x);
    val x1 = getX(p1);
    val x2 = getX(p2);
    val x3 = getFoo(#x)(p3);
in () end;
```

while the following commented out snippet results in an error because the types of
p1 and p3 are different, and so different invocations of getFoo
are required

```
(*
let val getX = getFoo(#x);
    val x1 = getX(p1);
    val x3 = getX(p3);
in () end;
*)
```

and the following is insufficient since it never resolves the record.

```
let val getX = getFoo(#x) in () end;
```